# Clockwork Mod Can't find backups

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid

Yesterday I performed a Nandroid Backup on my phone, because right after I knew I was going to wipe the phone and cache and remount Cyanogenmod on my Galaxy Nexus to hopefully solve another issue I had.

However, I guess when you do a new fresh mount CM recreates the `0` (profile) directory on the internal memory. So I ended up having to move the folders that contained the backup up one directory level.

The problem I have now is that with the latest backup I am running dangerously low on storage space, so I can't restore all my apps and data and therefore I need to delete an old backup (I have 3 but need only 2). I can't delete the folder using Astro or file manager even when giving them root access, and I thought if moving it to the same location as before CWM would be able to see it and delete, but it just says can't find any backups.

Is there a way to fix it so CWM can see it and I can delete?

The files are currently in the path `/storage/emulated/0/clockworkmod/backup`

Comment: Have you tried looking for these directories while booted in Recovery mode?

Answer (score 3):

ClockworkMod needs to be updated to properly understand Android 4.2's new filesystem structure so it can see its previous backups.

Technically, everything stored on the sdcard is actually stored under /data/media, however Android uses bind to essentially make a really fancy shortcut to various other places. This includes /storage/emulated/ and /sdcard.

As for deleting, without knowing the errors you were running into, it limits my options on recommendations. But you can use adb to delete files (with the code below, replace "old-backup" with the folder name containing the backup you want to remove).

```
adb shell
su
rm -rf /data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup/old-backup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by symlink.

1) remove clockwork dir  "rm -rf /data/media/clockworkmod"

2) switch to directory  "cd /data/media"

3) create a symbolic link  "ln -s /data/media/0/clockworkmod clockworkmod"

that should do it